# Autowire with value

Tags: spring-mvc, autowired

Is there a way to autowire a bean with constructor value specified from parent class .

Example :

```java
class ParentClass {

    @Autowired
    ChildClass childClass;

}

class ChildClass {

    @Autowired
    childClass(SessionFactory sessionfactory) {..}

}
```

I would like to have 2 beans in my parent class - one with qualifier 'A' for sessionfactory and another with qualifier 'B' for sessionfactory.

Is there a way to achieve this in Java ?

I would like to have something like this

```
class ParentClass {

    @Autowired (something to pass value a)
    ChildClass childClassWithA;


    @Autowired  (something to pass value b)
    ChildClass childClassWithB;
}
```

Is there a way to pass the constructor value from parent to child without creating two separate child classes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Qualifier` annotation.

```
class ParentClass {

    @Qualifier("childClassWithA")
    @Autowired
    ChildClass childClassWithA;

    @Qualifier("childClassWithB")
    @Autowired
    ChildClass childClassWithB;

}
```

The qualifier value can be specified either in the `@Component`/`@Service` annotation or using the `@Bean`annotaion together with `@Qualifier`.

As a fallback Spring uses the bean name as a default qualifier value.

Comment: This would  require separate bean definitions in xml for childclassA and childclassB. Without xml definition is there a way to distinguish and specify childClassWithA and childClassWithB for the qualifier ?

Comment: You probably won't come around defining two different beans. But why are you using XML definitions when you are already working with annotations?

Comment: I am still confused how to get two different beans based on constructor string value .How does @Qualifier("childClassWithA") know that it has to get a bean with constructor value "A" ?

Comment: Now, you got me confused. What do you exactly mean by A and B? Are those two different ChildClass instances using two different SessionFactories? Are the SessionFactories beans as well or are they simple POJOs? Maybe you can clarify your example and show how childClassWithA and childClassWithB are constructed.